# can I program directly into crystal reports or do I need visual studio?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Can i use vb or c# in crystal reports? Or do I need visual studio + plugin? It seems crystal reports only has a math function window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got better results with less keywords (which is often the case) [Modify Crystal Report without Visual Studio](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vscrystalreports/thread/16a44494-5378-42da-8072-84a8492c1ed0)

> One way would be to use a full version of Crystal Reports Designer and then you can load the report from the hard drive using a fully qualified path on the open/load statement. This way any change/updates or enhancements can be sent to the users PC's for use by simply copying or pasting the new report in that folder.

Comment: That doesn't really answer my question. Similar to Microsoft access, can I write code in crystal reports, or do I need to also use visual studio? I am not modifying code, because I do not have Visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

The only coding you can do from within Crystal Reports Designer is using their proprietary Crystal syntax, Basic syntax, or directly writing SQL in expressions or commands. You cannot create an entire report with code, but with the Designer, you wouldn't want to. There's no VB or C# supported in any way from within the Designer.